# Add ng-click in link function of directive

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function in my link-function in my directive:

```
var add_todos = function(todos) {
     html += "<ul>";
     for (var i = 0; i < todos.length; i++)
     {
           html += '<li> <input type="checkbox">'+ todos[i].title;
           add_todos(todos[i].children);
           html += '</li>';
     }
     html += "</ul>";
 };
```

I then use `element.replaceWith(html)`. This all works well, but I want to use `ng-if`in the checkbox. However, if I simply did `html += '<li> <input type="checkbox" ng-click="myFunction()">'+ todos[i].title;`, it wouldn't work, because, `html` isn't evaluated by angular anymore.

I do know that if I used a template, it would evaluate `ng-click()`, but I don't know how to use a template while maintaining the linking function. I've been thinking about having angularJS regard `html` as a template, which would mean that it would evaluate the `ng-click()`. I have no idea, however, how to do this. Other, perhaps more efficient means of getting this to work, are welcome too, of course.

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [`$compile`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile#usage) service:

```
var add_todos = function(todos) {
    var html = '…';

    var myListElement = $compile(html)($scope);
    element.replaceWith(myListElement);
};
```

But please don't overused `$compile`. In your example, a template with `ngRepeat` seems to be a far better idea!

Comment: Since I'm using the function recursively, using `ng-repeat` would require two directives that call each other, as shown here: http://sporto.github.io/blog/2013/06/24/nested-recursive-directives-in-angular/. Isn't my recursive function and using `$compile` more efficient then?

Comment: It's not about efficiency, it's about maintainability. The HTML code should be in HTML files, in templates, not lost in tons of JavaScript ;) .